# How do I create a component library that depends on material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two separate projects: A and B.

Both have common components that depend on material-ui.
I thought it would be sensible to have them on a single separate library C.

```
A -->
     C --> Material-UI
B -->
```

what's the correct way of doing it?

I'm trying `create-component-lib` but I'm getting `Error: Invalid hook call.`

Comment: Is this what you want? [link](https://www.devbridge.com/articles/a-step-by-step-build-to-build-a-sharable-components-library/)

Comment: @keikai the problem I have is that the library I try to create depends on Material-UI and material-table. They seem to prevent the creation of my own library. thanks!